# Flutter Firebase Auth: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate authentication on Flutter using `firebase_auth`.

However, whenever I call the `verifyPhoneNumber("+256XXXXXXXXXX")` I get the error message `A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.`, that is from the `PhoneVerificationFailed` callback. An for that reason cannot get the SMS.

I have tried;

1. Adding network permissions as seen below to my file (my internet  connection works, as I am able to Google via the emulator)

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`
2. Checking the validity of my API keys

I am totally confused as to why Flutter is unable to communicate with firebase. I have two questions.

1. How can I eliminate this error?
2. What other cases might cause this error besides a lacking internet connection?

My implimentatioin is as below;

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

var message;
// fire this when Phone verification is completed
 final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
      (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

    message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
    print(message);
  };

// fire this when Phone verification fails
  final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
      (AuthException authException) {
    message =
        'Phone verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}';
    print(message);
  };

  // fire this when SMS code is sent is sent.
  final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
      (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
    verificationId = verificationId;
    print('Sent verification code');
  };


  // fire this when smsCode expires
  final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
      (String verificationId) {
    verificationId = verificationId;
    print('Auto retrival time-out');
  };

// verify phone number
verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
      print('Verification Initiated');
}

// sign in with phone.
signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCode, String verificationId) async {
  final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
    verificationId: verificationId,
    smsCode: smsCode,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await auth.currentUser();

  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  if (user != null) {
    message = 'Successfully signed in, uid: ' + user.uid;
  } else {
    message = 'Sign in failed';
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
import 'package:badam/varify.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'HomePage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'FireBase Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new LoginPage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/loginpage' : (BuildContext context) => Dash(),
        '/landpage' : (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
    }
    );
  }
}
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String phoneNo, smsId, verificationId;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async{
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId){
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };
    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]){
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialoge(context).then((value){
        print('Signed In');
      });
    };
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential auth){
      print('verified');
    };
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verifyFailed = (AuthException e) {
      print('${e.message}');
    };
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNo,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
      verificationFailed: verifyFailed,
      codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
    );
  }
  Future<bool> smsCodeDialoge(BuildContext context){
    return showDialog(context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter OTP'),
          content: TextField(
            onChanged: (value)  {
              this.smsId  = value;
            },
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
                    if(user != null){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dash()),
                      );

                    }
                    else{
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn(smsId);
                    }

                  }
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Done', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.blue),))
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> signIn(String smsCode) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((user){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/loginpage');
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sign In')
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Phone Auth',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.blue),),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
              ),
              onChanged: (value){
                this.phoneNo = value;
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: verifyPhone,
            child: Text('Verify', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            elevation: 7.0,
            color: Colors.blue,

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It worked for me, hope this helps you!

Answer (score 26):

In my case I solved allowing **Outgoing Connections** on the Xcode's *Runner.xcworkspace*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in Flutter for Desktop (macos) build, Outgoing Connections was unchecked by default.

Comment: Why does here the Desktop (macos) build is relevant and not the iOS build? I mean it is an iOS App isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, my VPN was causing the problem. Disabling the VPN and testing it again solved the error. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

if you are trying this out in a simulator, then this error may pop up as the internet of your simulator is not connected. To solve this you can run your app on a physical device and it will work!

Comment: I would recommend you to add an explanation to your answer, not just code.

Comment: I faced same issue on physical device, I just disconnect internet and connected again, it worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Normally when the emulator is doing a lot of work on the thread, it tends to misbehave, such a `losing internet connectivity` even if your PC is well connected.
My suggestion(Which worked for me) is you kill the emulator, and go to `Android Studio AVD Manager` and `Wipe Data` for that Emulator, then restart the Emulator, it worked for me.[image: The circled in red are the key points to click]

- Kindly find below the image screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but I found another solution.

If using an android emulator, disabling the [Android Studio HTTP proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyETt.png) can restore the network connection.

Comment: Can you elaborate more here?

Answer (score 1):

*"I am late to the party but I found another solution.
If using an android emulator, disabling the [Android Studio HTTP proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyETt.png) settings can restore the network connection."* - **MaximeBeasse**

This network error has stopped me too and I have been seeking an answer ... After reading MaximeBeasse's response above and trying it out, I found that it worked : ) Authentication now works!  Finally I can move on!

Many thanks **@MaximeBeasse** -- salute his answer please

Answer (score 0):

Open `Terminal` in the project folder, run the following two commands:

```
adb kill-server
    
adb start-server
```

If `adb` is not recognized, add `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to environement variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in my case I could just solve it with:

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 0):

use the latest mobile emulators it works for me. before I used the Google Pixel 2 API emulator. I got the same error using this device. after I upgraded my emulator Google Pixel 7 error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have disabled the wifi. Once I enabled the wifi on the phone everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue trying to access the Internet via deploying to macos in debug mode. Turns out it was entitlements that were not set in:

`/Users/sparkyspider/StudioProjects/Helicopters/macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements`

See below on how to do it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>

    <!-- ADD THIS HERE TO ALLOW YOUR CLIENT INTERNET ACCESS -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> network error (such as timeout interrupted connection or unreachable host) has  ocurred

In my case the error occurred because I had configured to use the **auth emulator**, but it **was turned off**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was super simple. I'm using the Firebase emulator, and I forgot to start it. After starting the emulator, obviously, it worked fine.